# 'Wait for' vs 'expect'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, synonyms

In the phrase:

> "I [wait for]/[expect] a reply to my letter in the next few days."

Should I use *wait for* or *expect*?

I think it is "expect" but I don't have any explanation for it.

Comment: You may be waiting for or expecting a reply, but unless you are deliberately trying to annoy the recipient, it might be better to say that you hope for a reply.

Comment: @MichaelH - Agreed. At best, _expect_ will sound stilted; even worse, it may come off as quite rude.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting case I had cause to run into recently...

In some languages, there is no difference in translation between the English *wait for* and *expect*, and the idea of waiting for something without expect it is considered nonsense. Indeed, when I was working on something, it transpired that some dialects of English seem to consider them absolute synonyms, while in British English, in my experience, they are absolutely *not* absolute synonyms.

If you are **waiting** for something, there is no necessary sense that you are sure that it will happen, or that you will be displeased if it does not happen. If something is **expected**, however, there is a clear understanding that it is going to happen - or that if it does not happen, there will be consequences. It get more complicated if throw ***await*** into the mix...

If you are **waiting for** someone's reply, you are refraining from some sort of action until they reply, or just generally indicating that it would be good for them to reply. If they do not reply, it may inconvenience you, but you are not clearly suggesting that they are doing something wrong if they do not reply. Of course, there is an implicit suggestion that they should reply, and that they will have done something wrong if they inconvenience you, but the tone is not one of command.

If you **expect** their reply, then you are telling them that they should reply. It has a sense of command. There is an alternative nuance, which might be indicated by context or by the construction of the sentence, that simply indicates that you consider it a *rational* expectation that they will reply - that you are predicting that they will reply.

The tone also changes if you expect their reply *by some time/date*, potentially becoming a little less commanding but still with a definite sense of command. On the other hand if you are *waiting until some time/date* for their reply, it means that you will refrain from some sort of action (usually made clear in the text) until either they reply, or that time comes.

If you **await** their reply, there's a range of nuance, but I would say the usual one is that you are asking/hoping for them to reply, but no sense of command. It could even be positioning you as subservient to them, depending on context.

Examples:

> ... so I have to tell them something soon. I was hoping that you could give me some advice. **I will wait** for your reply.

You need to tell someone something, and you're waiting for this person to give you advice. You won't tell them anything until you get the reply.

> I can't complete this transaction until you let me know the name of the payee. **I am waiting** for your reply.

You aren't commanding them, but you are indicating some impatience.

> I want to get everyone's input before I publish the proposal, so **I will wait until next Tuesday** for your reply.

You're letting them know a time-frame for their response in order for you to take it into account. This is polite, neither commanding nor subservient.

> If these matters are not resolved, I will have to take legal action. **I expect your reply** soon.

You are threatening to take them to court. It is commanding and confrontational.

> In order to set the dates for meetings for the coming year, I need everyone to let me know their availability. **I expect** your replies **by 15th April**.

You are telling them that they need to give you the information, and telling them when to give it by. This is commanding, but not confrontational.

> I would appreciate your feedback on my manuscript. Your opinion is very valuable to me, and **I await** your reply.

You are humbly asking for someone to do something. There is no expectation that they will do so, but you reinforce with the choice of words - *await* - the idea that you would be very glad to receive their feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit, is the speaker speaking to the person whgo sent the letter, or a third party.

When addressed to the person who sent (or will send) the letter,

> I expect the letter in the next few days.

Indicates a requirement or demand that the letter be sent so as to arrive within this time. This would be even stronger with A SPECIFIC DATE:

> I expect the letter by Thursday the 14th.

On the other hand, when addressed to a third part in no way responsible for sending the letter:

> I expect the letter in the next few days.

merely expresses confidence that it will arrive within that time.

> I am waiting for a reply to my letter.

says nothing about then it is expected.

to indicate a time, but with less confidence, one might say

> I hope for a replay to my letter within the next few days.

One would not say

> I wait for a reply to my letter in the next few days.
>
> I am waiting for a reply to my letter in the next few days.

is possible but awkward.

> I am waiting for a reply to my letter and hope to get it in the next few days.

is perfectly fine. So is:

> I am waiting for a reply to my letter and expect to get it in the next few days.

Using 'within' instead of 'in' is slightly more formal, appropriate for a written business communication, not so likely in normal speech